# Regex pattern to identify attribute value

Tags: java, regex

I have a source code file which I am trying to read using a automatic Regex processor Class in java.

Although I am unable to form a correct regex pattern to get the values if it appears multiple times in the line.

The input text is:

```
<input name="id" type="radio" bgcolor="<bean:write name='color'/>" value="<bean:write name='nameProp' property='nameVal'/>" <logic:equal name="checkedStatus" value="0">checked</logic:equal>>
```

And I want the matcher.find to output following terms:

```
<bean:write name='color'/>
<bean:write name='nameProp' property='nameVal'/>
```

Kindly help to form the regex pattern for this scenario.

Comment: Ask yourself why you want to use regex for this. If the answer isn't "my professor is making us", then you probably really want to reconsider your design decision.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex to find those terms:

### `<bean:write[^\/]*\/>`

It will search for the words `<bean:write` and then everything up until a `/>`

Use it like this:

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<bean:write[^\\/]*\\/>")
                   .matcher(inputText);
while (m.find()) {
    matches.add(m.group());
}
```

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/sU8yR8/1)

I caution you though with parsing HTML with regex. If you need anything more complicated than this, you should probably consider using an XML parser instead. See [this famous answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)